# Starting create standard Java application using spring

Tags: java, spring

I would create Java standard application using spring framework but all the examples I had found on the web regard about creation of web application. How can I start to create standard application with Spring using MVC pattern?is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you need a simple application try to search in google  - framework name hello world.
in this case this is a simple spring http://www.roseindia.net/spring/spring3/spring-3-hello-world.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You would usually have a startup class which initializes a Spring context with a configuration. This should be enough to initialize and wire your objects together.

If you need to you can extract the object you want to get a reference to from the context.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the springsource toolsuite (Sts)? It provides different spring project templates.